# javascript function for input check not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have javascript function which is checking if some input fields are empty or some checkboxes are checked etc.

```
function empty() {
//NAME CHECK
var x;
x = document.getElementById("required").value;
if (x == "") {
    alert("Name is empty!");
    return false;
};

//CATEGORY CHECK
var selectedCat = document.getElementById('parent_cat');
if (selectedCat.selectedIndex.value != null) {
    alert("please, select category!");
    return false;
};

//price check
var priceBG;
priceBG = document.getElementById("requiredPriceBG").value;
if (priceBG == "") {
    alert("BG price is sempty!");
    return false;
};

var priceEN;
priceEN = document.getElementById("requiredPriceEN").value;
if (priceEN == "") {
    alert("En price is empty!");
    return false;
};

//Checkboxes check
var checkboxs = document.getElementsByName("amentities");
var okay = false;
for(var i = 0, l = checkboxs.length; i < l; i++){
    if(checkboxs[i].checked){
        okay = true;
        break;
    };
};

if(!okay){
    alert("At least one checkbox should be checked!");
    return false;
};
};
```

Nothing after the first check(name check) works. The name check works and then the form is submitted regardless of the other checks.
The html code is correct as far as I see and there are no duplicate IDs.
What can be the problem and is there a way to optimize the function?

Comment: You should avoid putting a semicolon after every closing brace, they don't cause any harm but they also don't achieve anything.

Comment: I put them because I thought that they may cause the problem.

Comment: plz check the browser console.do you see any errors?

Comment: I just saw: Unexpected end of input

Comment: Could you provide us with a fiddle?

Comment: I'm at work and can't do it right now. But I was thinking that the select menu is populated by php. Could that be somehow a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a correction for your code :

[Code pen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbAJPJ)

As Ursus said, it was selectedCat.value
Here is your code :

```
function empty() {
//NAME CHECK
var x;
x = document.getElementById("required").value;
if (x == "") {
    alert("Name is empty!");
    return false;
};

//CATEGORY CHECK
var selectedCat = document.getElementById('parent_cat');
if (selectedCat.value != null && selectedCat.value == "") {
    alert("please, select category!");
    return false;
};

//price check
var priceBG;
priceBG = document.getElementById("requiredPriceBG").value;
if (priceBG == "") {
    alert("BG price is sempty!");
    return false;
};

var priceEN;
priceEN = document.getElementById("requiredPriceEN").value;
if (priceEN == "") {
    alert("En price is empty!");
    return false;
};

//Checkboxes check
var checkboxs = document.getElementsByName("amentities");
var okay = false;
for(var i = 0, l = checkboxs.length; i < l; i++){
    if(checkboxs[i].checked){
        okay = true;
        break;
    };
};

if(!okay){
    alert("At least one checkbox should be checked!");
    return false;
};
};
```

Comment: After seeing your example I found out that you have put `value=""` on your first option. I only had disabled. I put it and everything works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`selectedCat.selectedIndex.value` shouldn't be `selectedCat.value`?
Also, check if you have some errors in the console.